How to hide taskbar icon of "GetOpenFileNameW" dialog?
I have created a hidden C++ console application in Code::Blocks. So, taskbar icon of application is not visible during execution.
I want to hide the taskbar icon of a GetOpenFileNameW() dialog.
Here is the code I have written to open that dialog:
#include "iostream"
#include "string_operations.h"
using namespace std;

///--- variables ---///
//-- HMODULE --//
HMODULE hmComDlg32;

//-- HWND --//
HWND hwndApplication;

//-- OPENFILENAMEW --//
OPENFILENAMEW ofn;

//-- size_t --//
size_t szSizeOfSelectedFilePaths;

//-- string --//
string strSelectedFilePath;

//-- vector<string> --//
vector<string> v_strSelectedFilePaths;

//-- wchar_t* --//
wchar_t* p_wcSelectedFilePaths;

int main()
{
    ZeroMemory(&ofn, sizeof(ofn));

    hwndApplication = GetConsoleWindow();

    p_wcSelectedFilePaths = new wchar_t[MAX_PATH];

    memset(p_wcSelectedFilePaths, 0, MAX_PATH * sizeof(wchar_t));

    ofn = {0};
    ofn.Flags = OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT | OFN_DONTADDTORECENT | OFN_EXPLORER | OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_PATHMUSTEXIST;
    ofn.hwndOwner = hwndApplication;
    ofn.lpstrFile = p_wcSelectedFilePaths;
    ofn.lpstrFilter = L"JSON Files (*.json)\0*.json\0PAS Files (*.pas)\0*.pas\0";
    ofn.lpstrTitle = L"Choose files.";
    ofn.lStructSize = sizeof(ofn);
    ofn.nMaxFile = MAX_PATH;

    hmComDlg32 = LoadLibraryW(L"ComDlg32.dll");

    if(hmComDlg32)
    {
        typedef WINBOOL (WINAPI *tdGetOpenFileNameW)(LPOPENFILENAMEW);
        tdGetOpenFileNameW fnGetOpenFileNameW = (tdGetOpenFileNameW)GetProcAddress(hmComDlg32, "GetOpenFileNameW");

        if(fnGetOpenFileNameW)
        {
            if(fnGetOpenFileNameW(&ofn))
            {
                while(*p_wcSelectedFilePaths)
                {
                    szSizeOfSelectedFilePaths = wcslen(p_wcSelectedFilePaths);
                    strSelectedFilePath = WideStringToUtf8String(wstring(p_wcSelectedFilePaths));

                    v_strSelectedFilePaths.push_back(strSelectedFilePath);

                    p_wcSelectedFilePaths += szSizeOfSelectedFilePaths + 1;
                }
            }
        }
        FreeLibrary(hmComDlg32);
    }
    delete [] p_wcSelectedFilePaths;

    return 0;
}

But, the dialog displays an icon in the Taskbar:

How can I hide that icon?

On a side note: #include "iostream" should be #include <iostream>. And all of your global variables should be moved inside of main() as local variables. And you are leaking the memory allocated for p_wcSelectedFilePaths, you need delete[], except ou are modifying p_wcSelectedFilePaths so you can't use delete[]correctly. Better to not usenew[]` in the first place, just use a fixed array instead.

You need to use the OPENFILENAMEW::hwndOwner field to specify an owner for the dialog window. The owner can be a hidden window that does not have a Taskbar button.

I have used hwndApplication = GetConsoleWindow(); and ofn.hwndOwner = hwndApplication;. The console application is hidden, so it does not have any taskbar icon. But the problem is the dialog still displays taskbar icon :(
